# Canvas drawPath is off

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have been trying to fill the polygon I am drawing in a Goole Map but
I can't get it right.  In my code below, when I just use drawPaint, it draws in the right location but when I use drawPath, It is painting the bitmap in different locations.

```
Bitmap fillBMP = PatternGenerator.makePattern(PatternGenerator.PATTERN_STYLE_X, lineColor);
BitmapShader fillBMPshader = new BitmapShader(fillBMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.REPEAT, BitmapShader.TileMode.REPEAT);
Paint paintshader = new Paint();
paintshader.setAntiAlias(true);
paintshader.setShader(fillBMPshader);

android.graphics.Point r1 = projection.toScreenLocation(mLatLngBounds.northeast);
android.graphics.Point r2 = projection.toScreenLocation(mLatLngBounds.southwest);

int width = Math.abs(Math.abs(r1.x) - Math.abs(r2.x));
int height = Math.abs(Math.abs(r2.y) - Math.abs(r1.y)); //Math.abs(r2.y - r1.y);


Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
//canvas.drawPaint(p);     // This works
canvas.drawPath(path, paintshader);  // This does not work.


GroundOverlay overlay = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
      .anchor(0f, 0f)
      .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm))
      .transparency(0.3f)
      .positionFromBounds(mLatLngBounds));
```

The Path I created is a series of points.

```
-23.725012,137.285156
-24.527135,145.371094
-29.382175,145.898438
-29.993002,138.691406
-23.725012,137.285156

int nPoints = mOuter.mCoordinates.size();

android.graphics.Point pos0 = projection.toScreenLocation(mOuter.mCoordinates.get(0));
path.moveTo(pos0.x, pos0.y);

for ( int i = 1; i < nPoints; i++)
{
  builder.include(mOuter.mCoordinates.get(i));

  android.graphics.Point pos = projection.toScreenLocation(mOuter.mCoordinates.get(i));
  path.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

}

path.close();
```

I used moveTo then lineTo and close the path.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by getting the bounding rect of the Path object.
And using the coordinates of the RectF to draw the bitmap 
and use the .left and .top of RectF to offset the starting position
of the path.

```
// This will get the bounding rect of the path and use
// the width and height of the rect to create the Bitmap.
RectF rectF = new RectF();
path.computeBounds(rectF, true);

int width = (int)rectF.width();
int height = (int)rectF.height();

Bitmap bmPattern = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmPattern);

// Need to Offset the origin so that it will drawn properly
canvas.translate(rectF.left * -1, rectF.top * -1);
canvas.drawPath(path, paintshader);
```